# Is it possible to link a method marked with MethodImplOptions.InternalCall to its implementation?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, reflector

In trying to find the possible cause of an exception, I'm following a code path using Reflector. I've got deeper and deeper, but ended up at a method call that looks like:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
private extern void SomeMethod(int someParameter);
```

This markup on the method tells the framework to call a C++ function somewhere. Is there any way to find out what method actually gets called, and in turn what else is likely to be called?

<sub>NB: I don't really want to see the source code of this method, I just want to know the possible things that could throw the exception I am seeing that originates out of this method call.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internal calls end up making a call to a C++ function in the CLR.  You can find them back in the [Rotor source code](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=8C09FD61-3F26-4555-AE17-3121B4F51D4D&displaylang=en).  Look at clr\src\vm\ecall.cpp to find the mapping from the .NET visible name to the CLR function name.  Beware that the source is getting dated.

Comment: Through a combination of http://www.koders.com/cpp/fid006DC4C11F458707221DA6ED2ED9CC3C7AE12E11.aspx and http://www.koders.com/cpp/fidFB82C2FF644D476EBEFA132529BA1A6DCA264698.aspx I managed to get what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to track down which methods can throw a given type of exception, you could use http://www.red-gate.com/products/Exception_Hunter/index.htm

Comment: I was aware of that tool. Does it also detect exceptions that are thrown as a result of code in the framework's C++ functions (eg. the one throw on this line -> http://www.koders.com/cpp/fidFB82C2FF644D476EBEFA132529BA1A6DCA264698.aspx#L1632)?